# Can we group specific data in different groups of ExpandableListView in android studio?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

So what I need to do is, that I need to group different canteen menus to different groups in ExpandableListView. In which the groups are the months and the child are the PDF menus. So is there any way to categorize the PDF'S in it's respective uploaded months. Like for example if MAY_Menu is uploaded in May and April_Menu is uploaded in April, they need to appear in there each group. Like MAY_Menu should be displayed in May and April_Menu displayed in April. The Code that I have written, according both are displaying in both months. So a little help would be appreciated.

So... any ideas??